# Efficiency of heat engines

Tags: thermodynamics, heat-engine, carnot-cycle

I have been taught that the an engine running on the Carnot's cycle has the maximum efficiency among any other engine cycle, however I never found a convincing proof for it. Wherever I have put this question up, everyone just said pit it up against any engine and it will come out with a higher efficiency.

I would like to know if there is any way to prove mathematically that the Carnot's cycle has the maximum efficiency among any cycle?

Also, I have the belief that the second law of thermodynamics is a consequence of the fact that the Carnot's cycle has the maximum efficiency among any cycle. Because the Carnot's cycle has come before the second law of thermodynamics, I suppose that the former points to the latter. Is it actually true that the second law of thermodynamics comes from Carnot's theorem, and is it possible to prove that a Carnot's cycle would have the maximum efficiency for a particular amount of heat given in?

Comment: What do you mean by maximum energy.

Comment: Sorry it's efficiency

Comment: OK, then see my answer

Comment: It if I remember the definition of entropy comes from the fact that Carnot's cycle has the highest entropy.

Comment: The Carnot cycle is a reversible cycle in which zero entropy is generated. Not sure where you got the idea of it having the "highest entropy".

Comment: No no if you see in the Feynman lectures on physics volume 1 chapter 44, he has said that Carnot's cycle is a reversible quantity, and it turns out that for the engine which follows the Carnot's cycle a quantity, Q/T remained constant, which is how he came into entropy

Comment: i.e he implied entropy change is zero for reversible processes

Comment: You have it backwards. Entropy change is not necessarily zero for a reversible process. Entropy change is zero for a reversible CYCLE. For the reversible isothermal expansion process in the cycle the system entropy change is $+\frac{Q_{H}}{T_H}$. Then for the reversible isothermal compression process the entropy change is $-\frac{Q_{L}}{T_L}$ for a net entropy change of zero. The two reversible adiabatic processes involve no entropy change. I think you need to take a closer look at the Carnot Cycle.

Comment: Okay can you suggest a proper source

Comment: Actually, Feynman lectures probably have one of the best explanations of this starting from a rather well accepted empirical fact - that you can't transfer heat from a cold body to a hot body without performing work. This assumption forces all reversible engines operating between two temperatures to be maximally efficient. And the Carnot cycle just happens to be one of the simplest examples of a reversible engine. Hence the claim.

Comment: @SKDash Feynman is good but I have found that thermodynamics is not his stronger suit. Any good thermodynamics text book can give you a good explanation of the Carnot cycle. One of the most respected thermodynamicists is Mark Zemansky. I was a able to download his seventh edition of Heat and Thermodynamics co-authored with Richard Dittman free off the internet.

Comment: You have added a good bit to your question. Typically this isn't the best thing to do, especially if there are already answers to your question. What about BobD's answer is not sufficient for you?

Comment: He said that second law of thermodynamics implies that Carnot's cycle is the most efficient cycle, however when I did some research of my own, of what I have understood, Carnot's cycle (Carnot's theorem) had come first and then the second law of thermodynamics, I wanted to know if there is a proof of Carnot's cycle being the most efficient one without using second law of thermodynamics.

Comment: When Carnot gave his Theorem, there was no second law of thermodynamics, so how did he claim $\eta$ was $\eta_{max}$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you mean maximum efficiency when you say maximum energy, then the proof is by contradiction. Essentially, in order for a heat engine to be more efficient than a Carnot engine it would have to violate the second law of thermodynamics. Rather than for me to give you that proof, you can see it for yourself in the following link:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carnot%27s_theorem_%28thermodynamics%29

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Efficiency of heat engines:

Essentially, in order for a heat engine to be more efficient than a Carnot engine it would have to violate the second law of thermodynamics.[image: mathematical prove]

Comment: Please don't use screenshots and type the equations properly (simple Mathjax syntax is available here).

Answer (score 0):

You are right, we can improve the Carnot efficiency cycle.

The first counter-example engine you can use to prove that fact is the thermosiphon.
In a thermosiphon, you have 2 sets of parameters:
the hot source and the cold source and the height of the thermosiphon.

You can increase the power of your thermosiphon by 3 ways:

- increasing only the step of temperature between the hot and cold source
- increasing only the height the U of your thermosiphon.
- increasing both parameters together.

The Carnot efficiency theorem uses nowhere the gravity and the possibility to gain or lose (potential) energy into a gravitational field. The thermosiphon can produce motion of matter without engine.

In the set of hypotheses of the Carnot's theorem, the hot source and the cold source are at the same gravitational potential. So, If you impose the constraint that both heat and cold sources will be at the same gravitational potential for your engine, there is no way to improve the performance.

But in reality, mostly regarding the environment, we are living into 2 well different gradients:

- The temperature gradient
- The gravitational gradient

Depending on the orientation of the temperature gradient, we can improve your efficiency or lower it, if the temperature gradient is not a the correct direction of the gravitational gradient.

The main model example to understand the problem is to suppose you are able to float into the atmosphere of a giant gas planet like Jupiter, and you planned to build a geothermal engine to produce energy from heat and cold layers of the atmosphere of the giant gas planet.

Your engine will have a floating condenser into the coldest layer of the atmosphere and a floating boiler in a hot layer of the atmosphere. The boiler will send steam into a Carnot engine, you will get the Carnot efficiency, but on the cold part of the loop at the highest gravitational potential, you can use that gravitational potential to add a water turbine before joining the boiler.

In summary, to enhance the Carnot's efficiency engine theorem, you must move the cold source into the highest point of a gravitational field, the hot source at the lowest point of the gravitational potential and you can produce energy on both sides of the loop, on the hot side with a classic steam engine and on the cold side by using a water turbine.

Your working fluid has to change its thermodynamic phase from gas to liquid into the condenser. For the thermosiphon, it is not required.

For people that will definitely refuse that truth, I suggest to ask them how the water fills the reservoir a dam on our planet Earth ?

Is the rain process a thermal process ?

The rain is not magic process, the water evaporates at sea level, condensates in high altitude, falls on the mountains, then the men just build a reservoir and install the water turbine.

That optimization is only available when you associate together both parameters, a step of temperature AND a step of potential gravitational energy along the cycle of your engine.

The Carnot's efficiency theorem concerns embed engines for a car, a train, a boat or a plane. If you're embedded into a gravitational field, you can use it to improve your efficiency if your engine is at least high enough as a dam on Earth. But gravitational enhanced Carnot's engine are sized for a planet as a dam is.